# string operation -need a better way

Tags: c++

I have a required where i need to extract a number from a string in the needed format like :

- f001-->100
- f100-->1
- 2030-->302
- 0203-->3020
- 2031-->1302

so the operation above is :

- remove any f character if it is present
- reverse the string
- remove leading zeros from the string

I have written a code which is working fine in c++:

```
int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{

string str1(argv[argc-1]);


reverse(str1.begin(),str1.end());
str1.erase(remove(str1.begin(),str1.end(),'f'),str1.end());
str1.erase(0,str1.find_first_not_of('0',0));

cout <<str1<<endl;

return 0;

}
```

is there any better way of doing the same thing?

Comment: @david...i need this operation in some what less code as i have to perform this multiple times in my code.Also i am not sure about the performance!

Comment: even further less ?? I thought you needed more performance..in that case you caould have gone for C-style parsing

Comment: ¤ If performance is an/the issue, then structure the code so that all removals are from the end of the string, to avoid shifting the characters within the string. To abide by the DRY principle (Don't Repeat Yourself), put this in an `inline` function. Cheers & hth.,

Comment: why not write a function to do this and declare it as inline?

Comment: In your question you say to remove the character `f` and then to reverse the string, but your code does the opposite. Is there a 'right' order for that? I mean, have you to remove the character **before** reversing the string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Guess, a simple function as below will do the job

NOTE:- It is not a complete program. Just a flow... It will parse the string once in stead of 3 times as in your case. I definitely hope there are better C++ style approach, and looking forward to the same.

foo(char* str) {

int state=0;

int len=strlen(str);

for(i=len-1; i>=0; i++) {

```
if(state==0 && str[i]!='0') { //Ignore trailing zeros
    state=1;
}
else if(stare==1) {
    if(str[i]=='f')
        break;
    //Reverse logic here, just store the char in a heap as it comes which will be returned after the for finishes
}
```

}

}